# In Django, how to count the number of data in model and output in admin?

Tags: python, django, dataframe, django-models

I am building a model by Django, similar to the below one. I will import the food data one by one like {supermarket_id, Fruit, apple}. At the end, I want to count, in the same supermarket, how many food belong to Fruit category and show it in the admin page. How can I achieve this? Besides, should I separate the category into a new class and make it as a ForeignKey? Many Thank.

```
models.py
class Food(BaseModel):
    CATEGORY_TYPE = ['Vegetable', 'Meat', 'Fruit']
    #supermarket foreignkey contain the id 
    supermarket = models.ForeignKey(SuperMarket, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    verbose_name='supermarket', help_text='supermarket')
    category = models.CharField(max_length=64,
                            choices=CATEGORY_TYPE,
                            default=CATEGORY_TYPE[0][0],
                            verbose_name="Food_Cetagory",
                            help_text="Food_Category"
                           )

    food = models.CharField(max_length=128,
                        default="NULL",
                        verbose_name="Name",
                        help_text="Name"
                        )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Food_Pyramid'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Food_Pyramid'

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s:%s' % (self.category, self.food)

class Supermarket(BaseModel):
    id = models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, verbose_name='ID', help_text="ID")
    name = models.CharField('name', max_length=64, help_text="name")
    fruit_count = models.IntegerField('fruit_count', help_text='fruit_count')
    class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Supermarket'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Supermarket'

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s:%s' % (self.id, self.name)

    def count_fruit_number(self):
        self.fruit_count = Food.objects.filter(category="Fruit", supermarket = 1).count

admin.py
class FoodAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("supermarket", "category", "food", "number")
```

Comment: That makes 3 questions... hints: question 1 ("count, in the same supermarket, how many food belong to Fruit category"): read the ORM doc and test queries in the Django shell - question 2 ("show it in the admin page"): depends on where in the admin you want to show this (and how), but reading the admin's doc and the various online articles about admin override should get you started, and question 3 ("should I separate the category into a new class and make it as a ForeignKey"): if you want to allow admins to add/edit categories, yes. Else, that's unnecessary extra work for you and the database.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Thanks for your hints!

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I have updated the supermarket class above. I have already figured out how to query the number but when I want to show it in the field by the function count_fruit_number(self), it shows nothing. Whats going wrong? Thanks again

Comment: "I have already figured out how to query the number " => I'm afraid you don't.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers but I can get the number in Django shell by the above query

Comment: First, `Food.objects.filter(category="Fruit")` returns a `Queryset|, not an integer. Then, it doesn't filter on the current supermarket.

Comment: Sorry, its a typo. the query should be `Food.objects.filter(category="Fruit", supermarket="1").count()` . Now, I just don't know how to automatically pass the data to the admin page.

Comment: It should be `self.food_set.filter(category="Fruit").count()` actually. And you should return the value, not store it in model field (it's a dynamic computed value so storing it will either lead to stale data or require updating the value each and every time a 'Food' is created or deleted).

Comment: And you STILL didn't explain exactly where in the admin you want it to appear (you have at least two admin views per model - the list view and the detail view) - but you certainly want to read the doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display